# Why did my MySQL slow down after migrating from GCP to Azure?

Tags: mysql

I migrated my MySQL database from GCP to Azure (both 5.7), but it seems to have affected performance.

```
Server before migration: 2 VCPUS with 7.5GB memory
Server after migration: 2 VCPUS with 8GB memory
```

Both servers run / ran version 5.7 of the MySQL server. My database is currently around 6GB in size, growing 100MB+ a day. It only consists of 32 tables, although a fraction of them tables enter the millions of rows category.

I read up on `innodb_buffer_pool_size`, GCP apparently sets it to around 80% of the memory, which would make it 6GB. I have set the `innodb_buffer_pool_size` on the new server to the same value.

Before updating this value (when I first noticed decreased performance), `innodb_buffer_pool_size` was set to 0.1 GB on the new server, I then decided to update this to the value the GCP server was set at hoping it would help.

Following [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-buffer-pool-resize.html#innodb-buffer-pool-online-resize) documentation I was able to update the buffer pool size.

**How did I check the innodb_buffer_pool_size initially?**

```
-- returned 0.111...
SELECT @@innodb_buffer_pool_size/1024/1024/1024;
```

**How did I update innodb_buffer_pool_size?**

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_buffer_pool_size=6442450944;
```

I checked the resize status with this query,

```
-- returned 'Completed resizing buffer pool at 200920 13:46:20.'
SHOW STATUS WHERE Variable_name='InnoDB_buffer_pool_resize_status';
```

I execute around 2 queries a second, peaking at 250k a day spread out. I can't be certain but this usage shouldn't be enough to halt performance?

**How am I checking performance?**

I have shown a list of queries ran, and the times it takes for the server to respond. I have tested these queries in Navicat, Datagrip, and CLI with similar results.

I wasn't sure what queries to include here to give as much information as possible, so if I haven't included anything useful I can update it upon request.

```
-- Fetching 100k rows from a 3.1m rows table
-- Time took: 21.248s
SELECT * FROM `profile_connections` LIMIT 100000;

-- (SECOND TIME) Fetching 100k rows from a 3.1m rows table
-- Time took: 1.735s
SELECT * FROM `profile_connections` LIMIT 100000;

- Fetching a random row from a 3.1m row table 
-- Time took: 0.857s
SELECT * FROM `profile_connections` WHERE `id` = 2355895 LIMIT 1;

-- (SECOND TIME) Fetching a random row from a 3.1m row table 
-- Time took: 0.850s
SELECT * FROM `profile_connections` WHERE `id` = 2355895 LIMIT 1;

-- Fetching all rows from a 20 row table
-- Time took: 40.010s
SELECT * FROM `profile_types`

-- (SECOND) Fetching all rows from a 20 row table
-- Time took: 0.850s
SELECT * FROM `profile_types`
```

But at times, I can run all of the above queries and get a response in 2 - 5 seconds. Performance seems to be hit or miss, there are huge differences in times taken for the same query, depending on when it is run which I am currently struggling to diagnose.

I ran [mysqltuner](https://github.com/major/MySQLTuner-perl) and got these performance metrics back:

```
[--] Up for: 47m 39s (38K q [13.354 qps], 1K conn, TX: 403M, RX: 63M)
[--] Reads / Writes: 50% / 50%
[--] Binary logging is disabled
[--] Physical Memory     : 7.8G
[--] Max MySQL memory    : 146.8G
[--] Other process memory: 0B
[--] Total buffers: 6.0G global + 954.7M per thread (151 max threads)
[--] P_S Max memory usage: 72B
[--] Galera GCache Max memory usage: 0B
[!!] Maximum reached memory usage: 21.9G (281.61% of installed RAM)
[!!] Maximum possible memory usage: 146.8G (1888.34% of installed RAM)
[!!] Overall possible memory usage with other process exceeded memory
[OK] Slow queries: 3% (1K/38K)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 11% (17/151)
[OK] Aborted connections: 0.67%  (9/1342)
[!!] name resolution is active : a reverse name resolution is made for each new connection and can reduce performance
[OK] Query cache is disabled by default due to mutex contention on multiprocessor machines.
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (0 temp sorts / 41 sorts)
[OK] No joins without indexes
[OK] Temporary tables created on disk: 4% (82 on disk / 1K total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 98% (17 created / 1K connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 63% (667 open / 1K opened)
[OK] table_definition_cache(1400) is upper than number of tables(302)
[OK] Open file limit used: 1% (55/5K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 100% (1K immediate / 1K locks)
```

**Slow query logs**
I run a lot of the same queries, so I've truncated it to include just a few.

```
# Time: 2020-09-20T16:45:04.230173Z
# User@Host: root[root] @  [51.132.38.176]  Id:     7
# Query_time: 1.022011  Lock_time: 0.000084 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 1058161
SET timestamp=1600620304;
SELECT @id := `id`,`item`
                    FROM `queue_items`
                    WHERE `processed_at` IS NULL AND `completed_at` IS NULL AND `confirmed` = '1'ORDER BY `id` ASC
                    LIMIT 1
                    FOR UPDATE;
# Time: 2020-09-20T16:45:09.676613Z
# User@Host: root[root] @  [51.132.38.176]  Id:     5
# Query_time: 1.198063  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
SET timestamp=1600620309;
COMMIT;
# Time: 2020-09-20T16:45:22.938081Z
# User@Host: root[root] @  [51.105.34.135]  Id:     4
# Query_time: 5.426964  Lock_time: 0.000133 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
SET timestamp=1600620322;
UPDATE `queue_items` SET `completed_at` = '2020-09-20 16:45:17', `updated_at` = '2020-09-20 16:45:17' WHERE `id` = 1818617;
```

Structure for the `queue_items` table, as requested.

```
/*
 Navicat MySQL Data Transfer

 Target Server Type    : MySQL
 Target Server Version : 50731
 File Encoding         : 65001

 Date: 20/09/2020 21:28:41
*/

SET NAMES utf8mb4;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for queue_items
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `queue_items`;
CREATE TABLE `queue_items`  (
  `id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `item` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `worker_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `type_id` bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `confirmed` enum('0','1') CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `optimized` enum('0','1') CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `owner_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `processed_at` datetime(0) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `completed_at` datetime(0) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp(0) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp(0) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `json_data` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NULL,
  `check_state` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NULL DEFAULT 'unchecked',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
  UNIQUE INDEX `queue_items_item_unique`(`item`) USING BTREE,
  INDEX `queue_items_type_id_foreign`(`type_id`) USING BTREE,
  CONSTRAINT `queue_items_type_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`type_id`) REFERENCES `queue_types` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT
) ENGINE = InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT = 6515764 CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_unicode_ci ROW_FORMAT = DYNAMIC;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Comment: Please post A) TEXT results of SHOW CREATE TABLE queue_items; and B) complete report from MySQLTuner after 24 hours uptime.  47 minutes is just a starter sample of workload.  The complete report will have additional useful information for analysis. What OS version are you running on the new AZURE instance?  MySQL is version 5.7.??

Comment: Hi! I am using Ubuntu 18.04 server edition, it is the newest Azure supports ATM. I am using 5.7 for the MySQL database. I have updated my question with the structure for `queue_items` table.

Comment: Potentially crucial information that I didn't include in the question, `top` returns that the process `mysqld` is using upwards of 90% CPU for the majority of its runtime. Memory usage seems to be normal, varying between 15 - 30%

Comment: Wilson Hauck mentioned a very important point: the innodb buffer needs to be filled to be effective. Your new server needs to run for a while on the same workload as the old server, reading the same relevant pages from the tablespace and filling the buffer with it. Comparing old (i assume still running) server performance with the newly booted one will mislead you.

Comment: @jacks regarding the 80% cpu time (i assume also when idle, ie not running queries): might be indication of the server rebuilding the indexes, reordering tablespace after a lot of inserts ... RDBMS are complicated, and there is much to be done under the hoodand a lot of cleanup in between. Let the server rest for a while.

Comment: @Kaii thanks for mentioning that, the new server has been up for a little over 48 hours, the uptime posted (40mins) is just low due to a few recent restarts of the MySQL server. When you say let the server rest, do you mean shut down all connections and just let it sit for some time? How long are we talking?

Comment: @jacks uptime of the server is irrelevant in this regard, only the runtime of mysqld/maridbd matters.

Comment: Thank you. I will see how it does in the coming days once it has settled in. This would make sense as I had to gradually increase the resources of the first server (GCP) as the database got bigger.

Comment: you can force the buffer to fill by running a few queries on your own. If you run the same query a second time it should be significantly faster. (when the server is done building indexes!) you will see.

Comment: you might also investigate into `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;`

Comment: This is something I checked, and it has given mixed results. A lot of the rows returned are marked as 'Sleep' and have been most times I've checked recently, the others are marked as 'Query'. There does seem to be multiple rows from the same host marked as sleep which throws concerns IMO as the hosts in question only run one process which accesses the database. Or better said, it only uses one connection at a time before disposing it and creating a new one next time it needs to access the database.

Comment: Just to give a rough idea I currently have 14 processes and 10/14 are marked as sleep, the rest are marked as query commands. That and the fact that the state is almost always 'Sending data' on query commands.

Comment: Additional information request. 
Azure model?, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: SHOW CREATE TABLE queue_items; looks fine.  Your UPDATE for the specific 'id' had to be bumping heads with some intense process for it to take 5 seconds as indicated by the slow query log.

Comment: So for the additional information, the azure model (I'm assuming you mean the VM model) is Dv3. It does have a premium SSD of 50 GB, but that is the only disk. I will post the results of the others once the uptime is 24 hours.

Comment: Because your 'confirmed' column data type is enum, this query - SELECT @id := `id`,`item`
                    FROM `queue_items`
                    WHERE `processed_at` IS NULL AND `completed_at` IS NULL AND `confirmed` = '1'ORDER BY `id` ASC
                    LIMIT 1
                    FOR UPDATE; - should NOT have the quotes around the `confirmed` = value to avoid datatype conversion as you are scanning the table.  CPU cycles would be conserved.

Comment: @WilsonHauck thanks I'll apply the required updates to amend this. Here is the information you requested: https://pastebin.com/raw/vwUDtLsF - I don't beleive the extra 5 hours will make any difference in the information given, as I think the server should have seen the entire query workload now although I can update it at 24 hours also.

Comment: Please take into account that no connections have been made to the server in the last hour, we had to shut them all down. A simple `SELECT` query on a 40 row table was taking 30+ seconds and the performance has hit a stage where it was near unuseable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221817/discussion-between-jacks-and-wilson-hauck).

Comment: Let's schedule a day/time, please to continue in chat.  Thanks

Comment: I am free almost immediately as I have engaged notifications. I will discuss this more in chat.

Answer (score 0):

The differences in performances between the two servers are probably related to their overall configuration (e.g. processor, computing power, storage, etc.). Have you any number on the expected performances of the two machines?

Then, these results are to be expected if there are write locks with long queries on `profile_types`, or metadata locks stopping the query altogether:

```
-- Fetching all rows from a 20 row table
-- Time took: 40.010s
SELECT * FROM `profile_types`

-- (SECOND) Fetching all rows from a 20 row table
-- Time took: 0.850s
SELECT * FROM `profile_types`
```

One thing I notice is that you seem not to have indexes for some queries. Try creating this index:

```
CREATE INDEX queue_ndx ON queue_items(confirmed, processed_at, completed_at);
```

Comment: Thanks! Them queries don't have indexes because they were just to test performance, my production queries all have indexes and/or primary keys. The performance on both machines is near the same. I do need utf8mb4, this is because of the unicode data I store.

Comment: Yes, I checked and I mis-remembered. utf8mb4 is the way to go :-) .